# Tap-to-click sensitivity too high after 16.04 upgraded

Tags: 16.04, xps

After upgrading to 16.04, I'm having a problem with Logitech T650 touchpad.

It's now too sensitive for tap-to-click. Now frequently when I'm trying to simply move the pointer, a click-and-drag is registered. Extra clicks register when I'm scrolling with two fingers as well.

I don't want to lower /all/ touchpad sensitivity, just the level required to interpret a touch as a tap-to-click.

Where can I find this to change?

Comment: You can adjust the touchpad sensitivity using libinput quirks:

https://djorborn.medium.com/linux-trackpad-settings-sensitivity-and-more-f85d8882e5d3
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-pressure-debugging.html#touchpad-pressure-hwdb